# Comparing elements of deque and list

Tags: python, list, queue

I have currently this piece of code

```
import collections as c
a1 = ['a' , 'b','c']
q1 = c.deque(maxlen=3) 
q1.append('a')
q1.append('d')
q1.append('c')

q1 = list(q1)

counter = 0
for i in q1:
    if i == q1.dequeue():
        counter += 1
```

Is there any faster or more efficent way to compare the elements of 2 lists and evaluating the overlap between them? A set is not the way to go as i need the duplicate elements and they would have to be in order.

Lists are ordered elements. Hence my deqeue would have a length equivalent to the list.

I would to compute how much overlap is between the list and the dequeue.

Comment: What do you mean by "they would have to be in order"? Your current code does not enforce order. `a1 = ['c', 'a', 'b']` will return the same `counter` value as `a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. Your algorithm can definitely be improved (it's order m*n on the lengths of your two data structures) but the right way to do that will depend on what behavior you intend. Can you explain more precisely what value you're looking for? Number of elements in one list that are also in another, length of longest common subsequence, something else altogether?

Comment: Could you add some examples?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. modified accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your revised question, I would take advantage of the fact that deque objects can be iterated by running over the `zip` of the list and deque objects. EG:

```
import collections as c
a1 = ['a' , 'b','c']
q1 = c.deque(maxlen=3) 
q1.append('a')
q1.append('d')
q1.append('c')
counter = sum(1 if a == q else 0 for (a, q) in zip(a1, q1))
# or, they're basically equivalent
counter = sum(1 for (a, q) in zip(a1, q1) if a == q)
```

That will compute the number of indices at which a1 and q1 have the same value, ending as soon as either is exhausted (so if a1 is 100 elements long, only the first three will be checked).

Comment: Or `counter = sum(a == q for a, q in zip(a1, q1))`

Comment: I always feel dirty doing integer math over booleans.

Comment: You should follow the pyhtonic way not your feeling ;-)

Comment: I disagree that summing booleans as integers is the Pythonic way, though I cannot find any external source addressing the issue. For me, it falls under "explicit is better than implicit", but it's admittedly a matter of opinion and any local style guide.

Comment: Upon further thought, `sum(1 for (a, q) in zip(a1, q1) if a == q)` is at least as idiomatic.